# No such file or directory even the file is exist

Tags: command-line

I installed an emulator in my ubuntu which is rpcs3 then after I make it executable and try to execute this shows.

```
bash: ./rpcs3.AppImage: No such file or directory
```

Full log:

```
root@localhost:~# cd ./Downloads
root@localhost:~/Downloads# ls
PS3UPDAT.PUP rpcs3.AppImage 
root@localhost:~/Downloads# chmod u+x ./rpcs3.AppImage 
root@localhost:~/Downloads# ./rpcs3.AppImage
bash: ./rpcs3.AppImage: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Is still I got the message this is my log
"root@localhost:~# cd ./Downloads
root@localhost:~/Downloads# ls
PS3UPDAT.PUP  rpcs3.AppImage
root@localhost:~/Downloads# chmod u+x ./rpcs3.AppImage
root@localhost:~/Downloads# ./rpcs3.AppImage
bash: ./rpcs3.AppImage: No such file or directory
root@localhost:~/Downloads# 
"

Comment: Could you please provide OS details? Why do you run this as root?

Comment: Os: Ubuntu 21.04 aarch64, I just saw it on youtube

Comment: You have to know where the file is. Use `cd` and `ls` and `pwd` to find it. Note, `/root/Downloads` is not the same as `/home/nino/Downloads`. Lastly, don't run stuff as root.

Comment: Please provide the output of `ls -l` and `file ./rpcs3.AppImage`  this may help identify the problem. Is rpcs3.AppImage a symbolic link by any chance?

Comment: I've looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCS3, and it doesn't seem like it can work on aarch64. According to that page, all they support is AMD64.

Comment: ... so the error message is a bit confusing, but in the case of a binary executable file that has the wrong architecture for your hardware, the "no such file" that it's referring to is the dynamic loader (like `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`)

Comment: @vanadium you should take your own advice because that is clearly not the problem.  from his commands, he is obviously in the correct directory.

Comment: @johncs note the edit. My comment was before the information was added.